# Sum of a list of integer

Tags: java

I've this method to calculate the sum of th element of a list :

```
public int getSum() throws ParseException
    {
        int sum = 0;
        List<Integer>li = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add(this.getElement());
          for(Integer lis: li) 
                sum += lis;

        System.out.println("Sum is :"+sum);
        return sum;

    }
```

I didn't understand why this doesn't return the sum it returns just the element of the list.

getElement returns this :

```
Elements :10
Elements :10
Elements :10
Elements :16
Elements :16
Elements :16
Elements :16
Elements :4
```

etc.

My list returns this :

```
My list :[10]
My list :[10]
My list :[10]
My list :[16]
My list :[16]
My list :[16]
My list :[16]
My list :[4]
```

Have you some idea ?

Comment: well you are only adding one element to the list... you know 
 : ***li.add(this.getElement());***

Comment: Use a Debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: Please give an example of input and expected output.

Comment: We can't tell you what's in `li` based on the source code you posted. The best I can assume is that `this.getElement()`, as the name implies, just gives you a **single** element. So, the list only has one element, and the sum of all elements – is the element.

Comment: *I didn't understand why this doesn't return the sum* - uh, sum of what exactly?

Comment: FYI ` li.add()`will add only one element

Comment: You should add all of the relevant code.. Are you calling this function in a loop??

Comment: What is the return type of getElement() ?

Comment: If the idea is to call the method repeatedly, you probably want to declare `li` outside it.

Comment: @ValentinGenevrais Must be `int` or `Integer`.

Comment: @shmosel an Integer dont return that (Elements :16...)

Comment: @ValentinGenevrais He's probably printing it in a loop or something. I trust the compiler more than I do OP. Unless of course it's all a lie and it doesn't even compile...

Comment: I've added the element of my list to my code and the result of getElement()

Comment: Povide a [mcve] with data set in the `List<Integer>`. Show the result of it, if this works, then show exactly what is `this.getElement()` doing, since you call `List.add(E)`, this can only return an `Integer`/`int`. Adding some log don't help if we don't know where those are called. My guess is that you should use an unique `List` that will be populate each time you call `getSum()` (which is BAD !) instead of declaring it in the method.

Answer (score 3):

this is my code

```
    int sum = 0;
    List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
    li.add(1);
    li.add(2);
    li.add(3);
    for(Integer lis: li)
        sum += lis;
    System.out.println("Sum is :"+sum);
```

the result is

```
Sum is :6
```

so there is just one reason for your question:

```
li.add(this.getElement());
```

you got empty list in this line(not null)，you can print the content of `List<Integer> li`  to make sure

Comment: this.getElement()  return an array ,so you must use li.addAll(this.getElement());  instead of li.add(this.getElement());

Comment: I've edited my code